# Checking whether a linked list is palindrome. Cannot find the issue

Tags: python, linked-list

```
class Solution(object):
    def isPalindrome(self, head):
        """
        :type head: ListNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if head == None:
            return True

        if head.next == None:
            return True

        slow = head
        fast = head

        if fast.next.next == None:
            return fast.val == fast.next.val

        length = 1

        lenPtr = head

        while lenPtr.next != None:
            length += 1
            lenPtr = lenPtr.next

        while fast != None and fast.next != None:
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next

        if length % 2 == 0: # even
            rev = self.reverse(slow)

        else:
            rev = self.reverse(slow.next)

        slow = None

        print(rev.val,  head.val, head.next.val)
        return rev == head

    def reverse(self, head):

        if head.next == None:
            print('return head', head.val)
            return head

        tempHead = head

        while head.next != None:
            temp = head.next
            head.next = head.next.next
            temp.next = tempHead
            tempHead = temp

        return tempHead
```

Here is my solution for a coding interview question that finds whether a linked list is a palindrome.

My strategy is just to find the midpoint of the linked list by using two pointers with different speed and reverse the second half of the list and then compare with the first half.

After I debugged, the problem is that the first half of the linked list does not remove the last node when it's an odd-length list. For example, if an input is `1->0->1->None`, the second half will end up being `1->None` and the first half should be `1->None` too since I did `slow = None` after getting the reversed second half.

However, it seems like it still has the `0` node even after setting `slow = None`. This is very weird because `head.next == slow` returns `true` when I try to debug it.

What can possibly be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Think about `slow` as a *pointer* to a node in the list. Setting it to `None` doesn't change the node it pointed to before, it just sets `slow` to point to another node, or to a `None` node in your case. So it doesn't point to `0` anymore, but `0` still exists and still in its place, pointed by `head`.

So `head.next` is still pointing to the next node which is `0` and therefore the first half of your list is `1->0->None`.